Error building a table row from comma separated list when using listofitems package
I am trying to build a table in which a row is built by a function/command call. I can get everything to work if I pass each cell as a separate argument to the command, but that is going to be tedious and error prone whenever I create or update a row (a bunch of {}{}{}{} for each row).
I have tried to pass one argument that is a comma separated list, process that list in the function with the listofitems package. However, when I try to return a valid table row (with the &), I get an Undefined control sequence error. If I just return each element of the array, things work, but everything gets put into the first cell in the row.
The problem seems to with the use of the & and returning information out of the function. If I create a table within the function call, access the items in the list when building the table, the table builds and there is no compile error. However, this defeats the point of being able to build just one row, as each row will be based on a separate set of data, defined by another argument passed to the function.
\usepackage{listofitems}

% This function fails when called, with an undefined control sequence
\newcommand{\makerowfails}[1]{
    \readlist\rowlist{#1}%
    \rowlist[1] & \rowlist[2] & \rowlist[3] & \rowlist[4]
}

% This function works, but obviously does not return a valid table row
\newcommand{\makerowfails}[1]{
    \readlist\rowlist{#1}%
    \rowlist[1] \rowlist[2] \rowlist[3] \rowlist[4]
}

% Use of the readlist and array access works here, when building the table
\newcommand{\selfcontainedtable}[1]{
    \readlist\rowlist{#1}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}{cccc}
            key & nothing & something & else \\
            \rowlist[1] & \rowlist[2] & \rowlist[3] & \rowlist[4] \\
        \end{tabular} 
    \end{table}
}

\begin{document}
    \setsepchar{,}
    % This fails
    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}{cccc}
            key & nothing & something & else \\
            \makerowfails{1,23,5,4} \\
        \end{tabular} 
    \end{table}

    % This does not fail, but it puts everything in the first cell in the row
    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}{cccc}
            key & nothing & something & else \\
            \makerowworks{1,23,5,4} \\
        \end{tabular} 
    \end{table}

    % This works, but defeats the purpose of building each row separately (each row is based on a different set of specified data
    \selfcontainedtable{1,2,3,4}
\end{document}

Obviously this is a VERY simplified, watered down version of what I am doing. I'm doing a lot more in the functions to build / calculate the value of each cell. I've removed all of the other stuff happening in the function to help figure out what is going on and found that the root appears to be using '&' when trying to access items in the array.
In trying to do some research, I am not sure if I'm just using the readlist / listofitems package wrong, or if this is an expansion thing? Other than just copy-pasting some LaTex that someone else wrote that does expanding stuff, I've never explicitly done anything with it.
I have also tried using both readlist and greadlist

This question is similar to the one on Feeding a list into a tabular with listofitems.
The reason that \makerowfails does not work is that \rowlist is only defined in the first cell. This can be solved by using \greadlist.
However, it is unnecessary to use the package listofitems: the code below does not use it.
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \makerow { m }
  { \clist_use:nn {#1} { & } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
key & nothing & something & else\\
\makerow{1,23,5,4}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}


